# Change Interpolation symbols in angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, angularjs-interpolate

Building a project in angular5 where I want to use  **[[ ]]** for interpolation as start and end symbol.

Previously , Angularjs1.x has [$interpolateProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider) to customize these symbols, by default interpolation symbol is **{{}}** .

How can we achieve the same feature in angular 2+ versions ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is special option for Component metadata

```
@Component({
  ...
  interpolation: ['[[', ']]']
})
```

Ref: https://angular.io/api/core/Component#interpolation

Comment: Is it possible to do this for the whole app instead of component by component?

Comment: Hi, @SalvatoreIovene, You've to modify in componnet only.